# A characterization of bi-invariant metrics on a Lie group

Tags: manifolds, lie-groups, riemannian-geometry, lie-algebras

In chapter 1 of do Carmo's Riemannian Geometry the author makes the following claim:

> Let $G$ be a Lie group with identity element $e$ and let $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle_e$ be a positive blinear form on $\mathfrak g$ such that
> $$
> \langle[U, X], V \rangle = - \langle U, [V, X] \rangle \quad \forall U, V, X \in \mathfrak g \quad \quad (1)
> $$
> Then the riemannian metric induced on $G$ by the relation
> $$
> \langle u, v \rangle_x = \langle d(L_{x^{-1}})_x(u), d(L_{x^{-1}})_x(v) \rangle_e, \quad x \in G, \ u, v \in TxG
> $$
> is bi-invariant.

He says that the proof is easy but will be omitted. I am not finding it easy. I have tried using the definitions and showed that the metric is left-invariant:
$$
\langle d(L_x)_y (u), d(L_x)_y(v) \rangle_{xy} = \langle d(L_{(xy)^{-1}})_{xy} d(L_x)_y(u), d(L_{(xy)^{-1}})_{xy} d(L_x)_y(v) \rangle_e = \langle d(L_{y^{-1}x^{-1}} \circ L_x)_y(u), d(L_{y^{-1}x^{-1}} \circ L_x)_y(v) \rangle 
 = \langle d(L_{y^{-1}})_y(u), d(L_{y^{-1}})_y(v) \rangle_e = \langle u, v \rangle_y. 
$$

I am having trouble showing that it is also right-invariant. Also, I have no clue on where to use $(1)$.

Any hints will be the most appreciated.

Thanks in advance and kind regards.

Comment: This question had a downvote. I would appreciate input on how to make it better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would not call the proof easy, but it just needs general principles. An outline is as follows: Since you transport an inner product on the Lie algebra $\mathfrak g$ to all points of $G$, left invariance is clear (and this is verified in the computation in your question). If a metric is invariant under both left and right translation, then it is invariant under conjugations, which easily implies that the corresponding inner product on $\mathfrak g$ is $Ad$-invariant, i.e. $\langle Ad(g)(X),Ad(g)(Y)\rangle=\langle X,Y\rangle$ for all $g\in G$ and $X,Y\in\mathfrak g$. It is also easy to show that this $Ad$-invariance is equivalent to bi-invariance of the induced metric (basically since right translations can be obtained from conjugations and left translations). Finally, if $G$ is connected (which probably should be added to the assumptions) then invariance of the inner product under the adjoint representation of $G$ is equivalent to invariance under the corresponding infinitesimal representation of $\mathfrak g$. This reads as $\langle ad(Z)(X),Y\rangle +\langle X,ad(Z)(Y)\rangle=0$ for all $X,Y,Z\in\mathfrak g$, which (after small rearrangements) is exactly the condition you have.

Comment: Thank you very much. But what is the infinitesimal representation of a Lie algebra? I couldn't find it in Lee's Smooth Manifolds

Comment: @Danilo:  For any $g\in G$, conjugation by $g$, $C_g:G\rightarrow G$ fixes the identity $e$;  $geg^{-1} = e$.  Since $C_g$ is smooth, its differential $d_e C_g: T_e G\rightarrow T_e G$ is a linear map from $T_e G\cong \mathfrak{g}$ to itself.  In fact, as $C_g$ is a homomorphism, the differential preserves the Lie bracket.  The differential (commonly denoted $Ad(g)$) is what Andreas means by "infinitesimal representation".

Comment: Dear @JasonDeVito, thank you very much, but then it raises other questions. What is then the adjoint representation of $G$?

Just to add some context, I am not very familiar with the theory of smooth manifolds. My knowledge goes just a little further than Chapter 0 of the book in question.

Comment: I am afraid that without some background on Lie groups and on the Lie group / Lie algebra correspondence it is difficult to get much gain from that example. You actually have done most of the verification that a left invariant Riemannian metric is equivalent to an inner product on its Lie algebra. The rest is just that the condition on bi-invarance can be encoded as a property of that inner product, which can be verified using linear algebra.  The explicit form of the conditnion is a secondary issue. It can be nicely understood if you know Lie groups, but some background is needed.

Comment: Thanks, Andreas. I am writing some notes on Riemannian Geometry, with the intent of filling the gaps in do Carmo's book while I study the subject. I think I will let this go for a while, and return to it when my background on manifolds is more solid. Again, thank you very much.